# WebExtension onBeforeReuest is not trigger for request from fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-webrequest

New to web extension development & I'm trying this [example](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/http-response). However when I run this extension it does not trigger the listener.

This is the manifest file.

```
{
  "description": "Altering HTTP responses",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "http-response-filter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/http-response",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://localhost:8000/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["browser-polyfill.min.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "57.0a1"
    }
  }
}
```

And background.js

```
function listener(details) {
  console.log("event trigger"); // not reaching to here
  let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
  let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let encoder = new TextEncoder();

  filter.ondata = (event) => {
    console.log(event.data);
    let str = decoder.decode(event.data, { stream: true });
    str = str.replace(/Example/g, "WebExtension Example");
    filter.write(encoder.encode(str));
    filter.disconnect();
  };

  return {};
}

console.log("Extension"); // this prints on the extension's console

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {
    urls: ["http://localhost:8000/*"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest", "main_frame"],
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

I found out that I need to add `xmlhttprequest` to the filters in order to trigger `onBeforeRequest` for the requests made with fetch API or XmlHttpRequest. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType

I Have a sample html page runs with live-server. Here's the code snippet where I send the fetch request.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/ping")
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((dat) => console.log(dat))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help regarding this issue is really appreciate

Comment: Try omitting the port in the pattern: `"http://localhost/*"`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I tried it by updating the manifest file as well the background.js file. but still no luck. Also, I tried to replace the url with `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` for testing. but still not working for that :(

Comment: And you clicked the reload button on about:debugging page?

Comment: Yes. Even tried to remove and add again

Comment: And the page URL is `http://localhost` too? Otherwise you would need to add it to permissions.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. The web page started on `127.0.0.1`. I just added it and now its working. Thank you.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you add it to an answer ? I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest):

> To intercept resources loaded by a page (such as images, scripts, or stylesheets), the extension must have the host **permission for the resource as well as for the main page** requesting the resource.

So, you also need to add `127.0.0.1` in manifest.json because it's not the same as `localhost`, which can actually point to a different IP.

```json
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://localhost/",
    "*://127.0.0.1/"
  ]
```